# Flatten a Two Dimensional array going in a clockwise direction

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

Looking for a better solution to retrieving the values in a 2D array in a clockwise direction retrieving the values and add to a one dimensional array.

```
board = [[1, 4, 0, 5, 0],
         [0, 7, 3, 0, 0],
         [0, 6, 0, 9, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, 2, 0]]
```

Function `corkscrew()` which, given a two-dimensional list of integers, 
           shows the current player in each square from the 
           top left square to the center, going clockwise:

```
"""
                +------------------+
                                   |
                +--------------+   |
                |              |   |
                |   +------>   |   |
                |   |          |   |
                |   +----------+   |
                |                  |
                +------------------+

"""


For example, given the board array the function should return the following list:

[1, 4, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 3, 0, 9, 0, 6]
```

Current Solution:

```
    def get_row(board, index):
        """Generator to return the row value at the specified
        index(i.e column value)."""
        try:
            for v in board.pop(index):
                yield v
        except IndexError:
            raise StopIteration


    def get_column(board, index):
        for row in board:
            try:
                yield row.pop(index)
            except IndexError:
                raise StopIteration


    def get_values(board):
        """Generator to return the values in a specific row."""
        start = 0
        operations = ['right', 'down', 'left', 'up'] * 2 + ['right']
        for operation in operations:
            row = []
            if operation == 'right':
                row = list(get_row(board, start))
                start = len(row) - 1
            elif operation == 'down':
                row = list(get_column(board, start))
                start = len(row)
            elif operation == 'left':
                row = list(reversed(list(get_row(board, start - 1))))
            elif operation == 'up':
                if board and board[0]:
                    start = start + 1 - len(board[0])
                    row = get_column(board, start)
            for v in row:
                yield v


    def corkscrew(board):
        """Returns one dimensional array in going clockwise."""
        new_board = []
        # Clockwise pattern
        values = get_values(board)
        new_board.extend(values)
        return new_board
```

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: Scroll down to find python code.